# Add new reason for closing: Poorly formulated/illustrated post

Tags: feature-request

One of the comments under [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798473/getelementbyid-innerhtml-is-failing-to-change-text#26798473) reminded me of a question/suggestion I've had since soon after I joined this forum.

Posts are quite often closed due to them being poorly formulated and/or illustrated. Fortunately it has rarely happened to me, and while generally the closure is justified, the reason is then usually listed as the post being off-topic. But in case of an original post, off-topic relative to what?

Wouldn't it be less confusing for beginners if close-voters could pick the reason option "Poorly formulated/formatted/illustrated post"?

Comment: most of us got a pair of eyes... before submitting a question, one should always preview it and check if it looks reasonable... there are always a few good souls who go around and improve bad formatting through editing the question.

Comment: @vba4all: that concerns the pre-posting process.

Comment: @Mat: you're right! My mistake. Gonna edit the question.

Comment: We already have "unclear" and "ot/mvce" close reasons. What would this add?

Comment: @JanDvorak: I've never seen "ot/mvce". What does that stand for?

Comment: @FrankConijn off-topic/minimum verifiable complete example = "questions asking for debugging help must include the code, it must be reasonably sized etc."

Answer (score 7):

Bad wording is not a reason to close a post. Such posts are not off-topic. The question you linked to certainly is not off-topic for any such reasons.

Edit the post to improve the wording instead, down-vote otherwise. If the question is so unclear as to be unanswerable, we already have the *Unclear what you are asking* close reason. If the question asks to debug code and there is not enough code there or there isn't a clear problem description as to what the code needs to do and what output is expected and gotten instead, there is a *lacking clear problem statement* close reason.

If the post is not improved and doesn't receive decent answers, it'll be auto-deleted after 30 days anyway.

Comment: That question is indeed not off-topic. Still, a commenter states: "I'm tempted to vote off-topic because of asking 'Why doesn't my code work?' without posting the necessary code." Which I see happening quite often in closure processes - unless I'm mistaking? Also, that question was not unclear, it was just missing the (whole) code. Hence the 'poorly illustrated'.

Comment: @FrankConijn: there is a specific off-topic reason already for that: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*

Comment: @FrankConijn: and a comment is just a comment, not a vote. I see that no actual close votes were cast for that question.

Comment: The latter ('no actual votes were cast') wouldn't matter, because this is a question about principle features. But your comment above it does matter, and is exactly what I mean. So my suggestion is withdrawn. I'm just wondering then why I so often see a closure reason "Off-topic", while from the post we can see that it actually was due to what you describe.

Comment: @FrankConijn: you mean in the review queue? You can click on that header to see more detail; there are several close reasons grouped under the off-topic header.

Comment: I'm not sure. I can't find a good example right now of closed topics that cause my confusion, but I'll get back here if I do. Thanks for clearing it up so far.